# compiling caffe error: invalid use of incomplet type 'struct CV::Mat'

Tags: compiler-errors, caffe, pycaffe

i'm building the caffe envrionment. i refer to [caffe.berkeleyvision installation](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html) My linux is centos final 6.8 ,x86_64
 
now I've got to Compilation step. 
Both way,I got almost same error:

> 1.Compilation with Make

in the Caffe dir i hit the comanmand `cp Makefile.config.example Makefile.config` and Adjust Makefile.config where the direction to anaconda2
  Then I hit `make all` I got error messages point to `nvalid use of incomplet type 'struct CV::Mat'`

> 2.CMake Build

`mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..` and then `make all`,when `make` 
here is the error info

```
/usr/local/caffe-master/include/caffe/common.hpp:73: error: forward declaration  of ‘struct cv::Mat’
make[2]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/memory_data_layer.cpp.o] Err or 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/layers/data_layer.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/caffe/CMakeFiles/caffe.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm totally comfused that i need to change the code of Caffe? or opencv? I'm new liunxer and have work on this for 5 days. i tried uninstall and re-install all of those softwares. I really need someone to help me ……

Comment: Before `cmake ..`, did you hit `ccmake ..` to check whether your config is ok? It can give you some hint.

Comment: Check that the path to the header files of OpenCv is correct. If you can update your question with `Makefile.config`, we might be able to help more.